# Why is facebook only showing 2 of multiple images that debug detects via OG tag?

Tags: thumbnails, meta-tags

When adding a url link into facebook from a test website I created, I had 3 pictures uploaded and facebook showed all 3 thumbnails as choices.  The next time I added the exact same url link into facebook, it now only ever shows 2 instead of the possible 3 pictures.

I then noticed that for a lot of websites it is only showing 2 of multiple possible images.  Any idea what facebook has changed and what the "rules" are?  My test site is WordPress but I've noticed this issue with non-WordPress sites as well.

I did a bunch of research and tried using multiple OG image tags to force it to see more then 2 but again, facebook only shows 2 of multiple pictures even though the facebook debugger shows all possible pictures from the OG image tags.

I wanted to verify all 3 pictures were valid picture format/size so I remove one of the OG image tags to force it to show the other two and it does show them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you probably have 2 FB apps configured to your account. Disable one and keep only one active, Check out that